# java Non blocking network programming time out issue

Tags: java, network-programming, nio, nonblocking

I am writing ftp server in java using NIO non-blocking technology.
I want to prevent user from connect to my server and then do nothing.
Here is my code snippet:

```
ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
SocketChannel socketChannel = serverChannel.accept();
socketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(3000);
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
....................
```

It does not works. Um... is it possible to throw an exception when the user do nothing (e.g. say 15 minutes)?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
socketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(3000);
```

You've done it. But then you also put the channel into non-blocking mode, which prevents you getting timeout exceptions. If you're using  non-blocking mode, and therefore presumably also `select()`, you have to manage the timeout yourself.